# If I type in >> tree where does the 'tree' go?

Tags: redirect, tree, output

I need to use output redirection to show what tree does but the file that is created doesn't have the data in. How do I get the data?

Comment: Please post the command you are using. It is working fine for me.

Comment: I typed in ' >> tree' but it created an empty folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
tree >> output.txt
```